# Create PHP array from string for Mongo

Tags: php, arrays, mongodb, laravel-5

I have a `Laravel` installed with `Moloquent` (Mongo). `Mongo` ins't necessarily the problem, when the model loads the "JSON" record, it becomes a PHP associative array.
I need to be able to create a function in a model that returns an array element by a string.

for example:

```
$search1 = 'folder1/folder2/folder3/item';
//would look like: $array['folder1'][folder2'][folder3']['item']
$search2 = 'folder1/picture1/picture'; 
//would look like: $array['folder1'][picture1']['picture']

echo getRecord($search1);
echo getRecord($search2);    

function getRecord($str='') {
  //this function take path as string and return array
  return $result;
}
```

I guess I could use the `??` operator, but I have to form an array "check" meaning: 
How would I form the `$array['1']['2']['3']` if I have 3 elements deep or 1 (`$array['1']`), or 5 (`$array['1']['2']['3']['4']['5']`).

I am making an api to add an item or folder to Mongo.

**Input** : `"f1/f2/item"`

This function I have:

```
echo print_r($j->_arrayBuilder('f1/f2/item'), true);
public function _arrayBuilder($folderPath)
{
    $ret = array();
    $arr = explode('/', $folderPath);
    Log::info("Path Array:\n" . print_r($arr, true));
    $x = count($arr) - 1;
    Log::info("Count: " . $x);
    for ($i = 0; $i <= $x; $i++) {
        Log::info("Element of arr: " . $arr[$i]);
        $ret = array($arr[$i] => $ret);
    }
    return $ret;
}
```

**Current output**:

```
Array
(
    [item] => Array
        (
            [f2] => Array
                (
                    [f1] => Array
                        (
                         )
                )
        )
)
```

**Desire output:**

```
Array
(
    [f1] => Array
        (
            [f2] => Array
                (
                    [item] => Array
                        (
                         )
                )
        )
)
```

Note: I have tried PHP's array_reverse and it does not work on this.. Multidimensional and non-numeric..

Thank you.

Comment: Why do you consider using `??` here inproper? It does what you're asking your function to do: checking if value is set and returning something else if it does not.

Comment: It would work on the check, but how would I get there? I have to form an array "check" meaning, how would I form the $array['1']['2']['3'] if I have 3 elements deep or 1 ($array['1']), or 5 ($array['1']['2']['3']['4']['5']) I see where this could be unclear, I will update my question

Comment: So I didn't understand your question - even after you updated it. Can you please try to elaborate more? And you function is errored - you should not do `$arr = explode('/', $f);` and then `$arr = [];` it override the var

Comment: I updated it, and I did not mean to downvote you, I accidently hit it and I did not want anyone to think that the question was accepted... Thanks for your help.

Comment: @JamesBailey So from input "f1/f2/f3/f4/f5/item" you want to build something like `["f1" => ["f2" = > ["f3" => ["f4" => ["f5" => ["item" =>[]]]]]]]` ?

Comment: yes. It is also a note that when "upserting" into Mongo, I do not need to respect any other "branch" elements. so the array will always look like the example you used.

Comment: I just need to be able to "target" the nest on the array with a simple string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, You want to take input string `f1/f2/f3/f4/f5/item` and create `array("f1" => array("f2" => array("f3" => array("f4" => array("f5" => array("item" => array()))))))`

In order to do that you can use function close to what you tried as:

```
function buildArr($path) {
    $path = array_reverse(explode("/", $path)); // getting the path and reverse it
    $ret = array();
    foreach($path as $key)
        $ret = array($key => $ret);
    return $ret;
}
```

For input of `print_r(buildArr("f1/f2/item"));` it prints:

```
Array
(
    [f1] => Array
        (
            [f2] => Array
                (
                    [item] => Array
                        (
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

Hope that what you meant. If not feel free to comment

Comment: That is it. Thank you for you patience and help.